# Setting background image in react DOM. Unknown error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the background image in the below code but keep getting the following error. `Failed to construct 'Image': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.` Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong? Google has been quite fruitless.

```
Image(imageUrl) {
  return { backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})` };
}

render() {
  return(
    <ul className="listings-side-bar">
      {this.props.listingsInView.map( (content, idx) => (
        <li
          className="side-bar-item"
          key={idx}>
          <div
            className="side-bar-image"
            style={Image(content.picture)}>
          </div>
          {content.firstname}
          {content.lastname}
          {content.about}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to the method is incorrect. Also it would be better to avoid using keywords for method names. Try this :

```js
getImage(imageUrl) {
  return { backgroundImage: `url("${imageUrl}")` };
}

render() {
  return(
    <ul className="listings-side-bar">
      {this.props.listingsInView.map( (content, idx) => (
        <li
          className="side-bar-item"
          key={idx}>
          <div
            className="side-bar-image"
            style={this.getImage(content.picture)}>
          </div>
          {content.firstname}
          {content.lastname}
          {content.about}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
```